# Magento multicall XML/soap

Tags: xml, magento, soap

Is there a tool one could use to find the SOAP that gets called for a magento php call?

I'm attempting to write/read data from a magento site.  I'm not on-site and my code is implemented in a language other than PHP.  I have been rocking along quite well, but noticed recently the multicall method in V1.

The problem I have is that I can't find any documentation on the multicall api.  I see a lot of questions on it when I google, but no documentation.

I'm wondering if a Magento Guy/Girl out there could post the SOAP/XML for a nuts simple call to multicall.  Something I could use as a base to Jump off..

Answer (score 2):

My good friend in NewZealand sent me this snippet.  It's an example of the multicall..

THANKS DAN!

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:multiCall>
<sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">55444333222111c5eccf0bc5e3aea54d8</sessionId>
<calls SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[4]" xsi:type="ns1:FixedArray">
  <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">catalog_product.info</item>
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">51</item>
  </item>
  <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">catalog_product.info</item>
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">52</item>
  </item>
  <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">catalog_product.info</item>
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">53</item>
  </item>
  <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">catalog_product.info</item>
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">54</item>
  </item>
</calls>
<options xsi:nil="true"/>
</ns1:multiCall>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```